# Convert geometry set to simple features collection using `sf` in R

Tags: r, sf, st-geometry

How can `geometry set` objects be converted to `simple features collection` objects  with the package `sf` in R?  I want to add attribute data to the geometry but am prevented from doing so because `geometry set` excludes including data.

Converting `simple features collection` to `geometry set` is done using `st_geometry`, but what is the equivalent in reverse? See sample code below:

```
#load sample data set
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#etc

#convert to geometry collection
nc_geom<-st_geometry(nc)
#Geometry set for 100 features 
#geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#etc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to create a spatial data frame with `st_sf`:

```
nc2 = st_sf(geom=nc_geom)
class(nc2)
#[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

Then you can add extra columns:

```
nc2$ID=1:length(nc_geom)
nc2
#Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
#geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#dimension:      XY
#bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#epsg (SRID):    4267
#proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
#First 10 features:
#                             geom ID
#1  MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...  1
#2  MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...  2
#3  MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...  3
```